# When I use google analytics, i bind the click trigger on <a> tags , but the request named collect was canceled,

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I use google tag manager to post data to Google Analytics.

```
<a href="/somewhere" ga-data="123456">the link</a>
```

[image]

The request was canceled, but the Google Analytics has received the data of link from my web.

Who can tell me how to use "hitCallback" with gtm, or other solutions to fixed my question?

Comment: Can you be more clearer. Why do you mean exactly when you say "to post data to Google Analytics." ? Can you give us more information on your global context ? thanks.